# pytest: `foo is Enum.FOO` tests True locally, False on travis-ci

Tags: python, enums, pytest, travis-ci, pipenv

Halp! I'm having weird issues with checking equality for Enums. Locally my tests pass, but on Travis they fail. Here's a sample of a test failure from Travis:

```py
_____________________________ test_extract_object ______________________________
    def test_extract_object():
        """Test UmlCreator.extract_object()."""
        creator = UmlCreator(".")
        with pytest.raises(ValueError):
            creator.extract_object(["no", "klass", "included"])
        obj = creator.extract_object(
            [
                "public",
                "static",
                "class",
                "StaticKlass",
                ":",
                "ICanBeImplemented,",
                "IComparable,",
                "IEquatable<Klass>",
            ]
        )
        assert obj.__class__.__name__ == "UmlClass"
>       assert obj.access is Access.PUBLIC
E       assert Access("public") is Access("public")
E        +  where Access("public") = UmlClass(['StaticKlass', ':', 'ICanBeImplemented,', 'IComparable,', 'IEquatable<Klass>'], **{'nsp': None, 'access': Access("public"), 'attrs': [], 'modifiers': [Modifier("static")], 'repo_url': None}).access
E        +  and   Access("public") = Access.PUBLIC
tests/test_creator.py:44: AssertionError
```

If I change the offending line to `assert obj.access.value == Access.PUBLIC.value` it passes on Travis as well, but I'm stumped as to why this fails in one place and passes in another with basically the same setup, and it of course also affects non-test code, meaning that everywhere I use `foo is Enum.VAL` in my code, tests for those methods fail as well:

```py
tests/test_creator.py:44: AssertionError
_________________________ test_uml_class_display_name __________________________
    def test_uml_class_display_name():
        """Test UmlClass.display_name()."""
        klass = UmlClass(["Classy"])
        assert klass.display_name() == "Classy"
        abstract_klass = UmlClass(["Classy"], modifiers=[Modifier.ABSTRACT])
>       assert abstract_klass.is_abstract()
E       assert False
```

#### Local

```sh
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
$ pip list
Package            Version
------------------ --------
appdirs            1.4.3
astroid            2.3.3
attrs              19.3.0
bandit             1.6.2
black              19.10b0
Click              7.0
coverage           5.0.3
gitdb2             2.0.6
GitPython          3.0.7
importlib-metadata 1.5.0
isort              4.3.21
lazy-object-proxy  1.4.3
mccabe             0.6.1
more-itertools     8.2.0
packaging          20.1
pathspec           0.7.0
pbr                5.4.4
pip                20.0.2
pluggy             0.13.1
py                 1.8.1
pylint             2.4.4
pyparsing          2.4.6
pytest             5.3.5
pytest-cov         2.8.1
PyYAML             5.3
regex              2020.1.8
rope               0.16.0
setuptools         45.1.0
six                1.14.0
smmap2             2.0.5
stevedore          1.32.0
toml               0.10.0
typed-ast          1.4.1
wcwidth            0.1.8
wheel              0.34.2
wrapt              1.11.2
zipp               2.2.0
$ pipenv run test
===== test session starts =====
platform linux -- Python 3.6.9, pytest-5.3.5, py-1.8.1, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /mnt/c/Users/thy/source/repos/uml.cs, inifile: pytest.ini
plugins: cov-2.8.1
collected 41 items
```

#### Travis

```sh
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
$ pip list
Package            Version
------------------ ----------
appdirs            1.4.3
astroid            2.3.3
atomicwrites       1.3.0    !
attrs              19.3.0
bandit             1.6.2
black              19.10b0
certifi            2019.6.16 !
Click              7.0
coverage           5.0.3
gitdb2             2.0.6
GitPython          3.0.7
importlib-metadata 1.5.0
isort              4.3.21
lazy-object-proxy  1.4.3
mccabe             0.6.1
mock               3.0.5 !
more-itertools     8.2.0
nose               1.3.7 !
numpy              1.18.0 !
packaging          20.1
pathspec           0.7.0
pbr                5.4.4
pip                19.3.1
pipenv             2018.11.26
pluggy             0.13.1
py                 1.8.1
pylint             2.4.4
pyparsing          2.4.6
pytest             5.3.5
pytest-cov         2.8.1
PyYAML             5.3
regex              2020.1.8
rope               0.16.0
setuptools         42.0.2
six                1.14.0
smmap2             2.0.5
stevedore          1.32.0
toml               0.10.0
typed-ast          1.4.1
virtualenv         16.6.1
virtualenv-clone   0.5.3
wcwidth            0.1.8
wheel              0.33.6
wrapt              1.11.2
zipp               2.2.0
python -m pytest
===== test session starts =====
platform linux -- Python 3.6.9, pytest-5.3.5, py-1.8.1, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /home/travis/build/kthy/uml.cs, inifile: pytest.ini
plugins: cov-2.8.1
collected 41 items
```

For easier comparison, here's a table of the differences:

```
| Local (WSL)        | Travis                 |
| ------------------ | ---------------------- |
| Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS | Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS     |
|                    | atomicwrites-1.3.0     |
|                    | certifi-2019.6.16      |
|                    | mock-3.0.5             |
|                    | nose-1.3.7             |
|                    | numpy-1.18.0           |
| pip-20.0.2         | pip-19.3.1             |
|                    | pipenv-2018.11.26      |
| setuptools-45.1.0  | setuptools-42.0.2      |
|                    | virtualenv-16.6.1      |
|                    | virtualenv-clone-0.5.3 |
| wheel-0.34.2       | wheel-0.33.6           |
```

Full build log from Travis can be seen e.g. [here](https://travis-ci.org/kthy/uml.cs/jobs/650011953).

Comment: Where and how is the Enum created?  One likely culprit is that the module with the Enum defined is being imported more than once under different names.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen:  One of the selling points of Enum is they are unique and can be compared by object identity.  If there are files being imported under different names (which is what is required to show this particular bug) then that is something that kthy will need to get fixed.

Comment: Ok, thanks - learned [something new](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#comparisons). I'll delete my post to not confuse anyone.

Comment: Very happy to have caught your attention, @EthanFurman - before posting this question I had found [Issue30545](https://bugs.python.org/issue30545) but I didn't think it was applicable since my tests work locally. The code is at [github](https://github.com/kthy/uml.cs): the failing test in `tests/test_creator.py` where I do `from umldotcs.features import Access` and the code under test in `umldotcs/creator.py` where I have a try/except import statement: `try: \ from features import Access \ except (ImportError, ModuleNotFoundError): \ from umldotcs.features import Access`

Comment: Removing that try / except import in favour of a simple import from `umldotcs.features` makes the problem go away, so it seems it was completely a problem of my own making. What I don't get is why my own python and the one on Travis processes the imports differently when they are the same versions and all?

Comment: @kthy:  I have no idea.  You could make that a new question.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, [as pointed out by Ethan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60211486/pytest-foo-is-enum-foo-tests-true-locally-false-on-travis-ci#comment106505709_60211486) the problem was my imports. For whatever reason I was importing the `Enum`s like

```py
try:
  from features import Access
except (ImportError, ModuleNotFoundError):
  from umldotcs.features import Access
```

- I can't remember why, but probably because I had had some problems with imports before. **Cargo cult programming strikes again!**  Running `pytest` locally used the second import, whereas Travis for some reason chose the first, triggering [Issue30545](https://bugs.python.org/issue30545) which is user error, not a python bug. Making sure all `Enum`s were imported in the same way resolved the problem.